# Does printf terminate every string with null character?

Tags: c

We have a statement like-
printf("Hello World");
Does printf append a null character after 'd' in the given string?

Comment: No , `printf` does not do that in any case .

Answer (score 4):

When you write

```
printf("xyz");
```

you are actually passing a string consisting of three characters and a null-terminator to `printf`.

```
printf("xyz");
// is equivalent to
static const char xyz[] = { 'x', 'y', 'z', 0 };
printf(xyz);
```

both `printf`s have the same effect: they write the characters x, y and z to the console. The null-terminator is not written.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string0[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    char string1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c','\0'};
    printf("%s", string0);
    puts("");
    printf("%s", string1);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are lucky enough, you will see something like:

```
abc$#r4%&^3
abc
```

`printf()` does not append a `'\0'` to the string. It doesn't make any change to the string to be output, because its task is to "print", rather than "modify". **Instead, it is the null characters that tell `printf()` where is the end of the strings.**

Answer (score 0):

When a string is defined e.g. "hello world" it is null terminated by default. printf  does nothing related to null terminate expect its own print processing. It only accepts char* as input. In your example "Hello World" is temp string and null terminated already before passed to printf. If the passed string is not null terminated then the behavior is undefined.